# How to set Dark mode for the whole device for Android 10, 11, 12?

Tags: android, android-darkmode

I am trying to create an app that toggles the Dark Mode (Night mode) **for the whole system**. Not just for my app. I am creating and automation app, so the user decides what to enable or what to disable in just on touch.

To activate the Night mode I do this:

```
UiModeManager oUiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
oUiModeManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

and to deactivate I do this:

```
UiModeManager oUiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
oUiModeManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

But nothing happens. The dark mode doesn't get activated or deactivated.
I have tried with Android 10-Q, Android 11-R and Android 12-S devices.
So, how am I supposed to solve this? Remember I need to toggle the whole system dark mode, not just for my app.
Thanks

Issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173628055
But not answers from Google Developers.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem that these flags have any effect on the system. The Settings app [doesn't use them](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/display/darkmode/DarkModeActivationPreferenceController.java;l=141) to switch dark mode. 
The method, that the Settings app calls, [is hidden](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/UiModeManager.java;drc=master;l=514), so there is no legal way for an app to call it. 
I was able to turn on dark mode on android 11 using this method via reflection with a library to bypass reflection restrictions.

Comment: Thanks. But docs say "setNightMode: Sets the system-wide night mode".

Comment: See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager#setNightMode(int)

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue in android issue tracker then. Personally, I don't believe it has ever worked as described.

Comment: I think so too. Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how you did it? Which library, compileSdk, maybe a code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173628055

Answer (score -1):

Android offical has a sample [DarkTheme](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/DarkTheme).But I don't know if it works

Comment: That example shows how to set Dark theme for your own app. I am asking to change the Dark mode for the whole System.

Answer (score -1):

For Android 12 and above , use `setApplicationNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

Below Android 12, Use
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

See [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#change-themes) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager#setApplicationNightMode(int))